# Get-scheduled task to see history for more than last run

Tags: windows, powershell

when i run

```
Get-ScheduledTask -TaskName "ttasskkk" | Get-ScheduledTaskInfo
```

I receive info about last run time only. 
how to use PS to see results from last 7 runs or more ?

Comment: You might be better off looking at the log: `Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler/Operational`. I don't believe the history of the scheduled tasks is available in the PS cmdlet

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The history of scheduled tasks is not available in the `Get-ScheduledTask` cmdlet. What you can do is use `Get-WinEvent` to check the log `Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler/Operational` for the history of the task.

Here is an example using your taskname "`ttasskkk`":

```
$events = @(
     Get-WinEvent  -FilterXml @'
     <QueryList>
      <Query Id="0" Path="Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler/Operational">
       <Select Path="Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler/Operational">
        *[EventData/Data[@Name='TaskName']='\ttasskkk']
       </Select>
      </Query>
     </QueryList>
'@  -ErrorAction Stop -MaxEvents 2
)
$events
```

Comment: how we can pass the task name dynamically