# Powershell - how to get list of all jobs that had runs in the last hour From TASK Scheduler

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks, ps

how can I by using Powershell,
Get the list of all the Jobs that runs from TASK Scheduler with this filters:

1. only tasks that runs in the last hour
2. from sub TASK Scheduler library that is not Microsoft?

layout needed - name of the job, which time have been run, end time (if ended).

Comment: get-job gives jo a list of jobs. but once you close the shell the information is gone.

Comment: See: [Get-scheduled task to see history for more than last run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58012201/get-scheduled-task-to-see-history-for-more-than-last-run)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
get-scheduledtask|where-object{$_.taskpath -notmatch "^\\Microsoft"}|get-scheduledtaskinfo|where-object{$_.lastruntime -gt (get-date).addhours(-1)}
```

You can accomplish that with a one-liner that uses the following cmdlets:

- **get-scheduledtask** lists the existing scheduledtasks, here is where you need to filter the taskpath to avoid Microsoft subtasks
- **get-scheduledtaskinfo** list all the information of a certain task (or in this case, all the information of the task list received
  through the pipeline)
- **get-date** will give you current datetime, here you can add or substract time with the method **addhours()**

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?